# Building Automotive Grade Linux for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, automotive-grade-linux

I am currently trying to run the AGL demo platform on the RaspberryPi3.

I have proceeded according to the following instructions:
[Building the AGL Demo Platform for Raspberry Pi instructions](http://docs.automotivelinux.org/docs/getting_started/en/dev/reference/machines/raspberrypi.html)

However, the output Image *tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi3/agl-demo-platform-raspberrypi2.wic.xz* as specified in the link is not created when building with bitbake.
Instead only one image file is created: *tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi3/agl-demo-platform-raspberrypi3.rpi-sdimg.xz*

When trying to copy the image file to the SD card (with etcher and the following command line: 
`sudo dd if=./<file-Name.rpi-sdimg of>=<sdCard>`) the demo cannot be started. When booting the RaspberryPi only a black screen appears.

But if I use the following .wic.xz from 
[raspberrypi3/deploy/images/raspberrypi3 - Files](https://download.automotivelinux.org/AGL/snapshots/master/latest/raspberrypi3/deploy/images/raspberrypi3/)
and copy it to the SD card everything works fine.

Why does the image file not work and why does "Bitbake" not create a .wic.xz, although everything is done as described in the instructions from AGL?

Answer (score 0):

I had also got a similar error.
I do not know the reason but this fixed the issue.

```
xzcat output-img.xz | sudo dd of=[sdcard] bs=4M
```